# A problem involving the second derivative of a function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I need to show the following. For a smooth function $f(x)$, if $f''(x)<0$, and there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$ then $f(x)$ has at least one zero. Now I see that $f''(x)<0$ means that if I was to plot $f(x)$, then it would be concave down and would hit a zero at some $x$. But how do I prove this analytically?

Comment: False. Let $f(x)=-(x^2+1)$.

Comment: I edited the question now. It is for the case where I know that for some $x_0$, $f(x_0)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

As Parcly Taxel has pointed out in the comments, what you want to prove is not true.

You said,

> $f''(x)<0$ means that if I was to plot $f(x),$ then it would be
>   concave down and would hit a zero at some $x.$

The problem is with the last phrase (after the conjunction); since it's concave down, I can always drag down any curve that hits zero at some point away from zero again, and will always win, precisely because of the concavity. I hope you see why this is true in general and can now construct infinitely many counterexamples of your own.

---

The above was before OP edited post to include a condition he had not mentioned before.

Now, even if $f(x)>0$ at some point (I'm assuming the domain is an interval), then it still doesn't follow. Consider the function $y$ of $x$ defined by $x^2+y^2=1,$ where $|x| \le 1/2.$ Then it satisfies your conditions yet has no root there.

Comment: I edited the question. It is for the case where I know that there exists an $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)>0$.

Comment: @SoumilMaulick Even at that it's not true. See edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that because of the restriction of the domain, if you had chosen the 'natural' domain $|x| \leq 1$ for the function $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then you do hit a zero at $x= \pm 1$.

Comment: @SoumilMaulick There's nothing like natural domain. The domain of a function is a part of it. Thus, the same equation may define infinitely many functions, depending on how we choose domains, even codomains. In any case, a single counterexample is sufficient to disprove a claim. Also, I assumed it was clear how one could construct similar infinitely many counterexamples.

Comment: @SoumilMaulick Or, just take the equation $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ with the *'natural'* domain (to use your term), with codomain being all $y\ge1.$ Then this fulfills all your conditions yet has no root.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry for not being able to put the right details about the domain in the question. What I was trying to do is try to transalte the intuitive picture of a concave downwards graph  hitting zero into equations. Ok let me try to say this. Hope the following is well defined now. Take the domain $[x_0, \infty)$, $f(x_0)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ in the domain. Assume $f(x)$ is smooth. Now I think going by the graph it should have a root?

Comment: @SoumilMaulick Still, it is not the case. Consider the equation $x^2(y-1)^2=x^2-1$ and use it to define a function for $x\ge 1,$ and codomain being $y\ge 1.$ Then obviously there is no root for this function. You can check that it satisfies the conditions you gave.

Comment: @SoumilMaulick Another example is $\log x$ for any interval $[x,\infty),$ with $x>1.$